# Add custom variable to PHP Mail script

Tags: php, html

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['dnevne'] = $dnevne;


$email_to = "marioznik@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email_from = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$email_subject = "Price is: $dnevne ";
$headers = "From: " . $email_from . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_from . "\n";
ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
$sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, "-f" .$email_from);
if ($sent)
{
    header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/thankyou.html");
} else {
    echo "There has been an error sending your comments. Please try later.";
}
?>
```

I add few reccomended things, but still i can't get $dnevne variable to my e-mail. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I want to display value from variable $xyz in body of e-mail in $msg field.

Comment: @Serbon : you can add (almost) whatever [you need in a mail body](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) if properly formatted

Comment: @Serbon Just use $message = "$message $dnevne";` Use whatever format you need for the massage.

Comment: what's the point here ? OP never talked about $_SESSION at 1st sight... Maybe data (price ?) from the form, not sure at all as he didn't mention that, but most likely ? `$_SESSION['dnevne'] = $dnevne; ` will not be useful here, on top of the page sending mail !

Comment: @user4035, i try that but it doesn't display me value of $dnevne

Comment: @Serbon Is `$dnevne` stored in the session when you call the script? You must define it before using. Try ` $dnevne = $_SESSION['dnevne']` instead of `$_SESSION['dnevne'] = $dnevne;`

Comment: @Serbon : question is `where is set $dnevne` ? and `where does it come from` ? you can't use it for the mail if not previously defined

Comment: @OldPadawan , it's in index.php file, it's calculation variable ($dnevna = $nocna + $ukupno).

Comment: Then, I recommand putting this value in a hidden input of the form (so user can't mess with it), then access it through $_POST['dnevna'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you define a variable : `$dnevna = $nocna + $ukupno` on your 1st page, then, I recommand putting this value in a hidden input of the form (so user can't mess with it), then access it through `$dnevna = $_POST['dnevna'];`

The same thing your are doing with `$name = $_POST["name"]; $email_from = $_POST["email"]; $message = $_POST["message"];`

Then, you use [PHP doc -> mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to make your email formatted as you need, include all needed data, and send it to you...

No need to worry about `session`if you're not using them before...

Comment: What to put in hidden input in form, what value needs to be? http://jsfiddle.net/b09et3ja/   , here you can take better look in my practice code.

Comment: I also tried to add index.php to sendmail.php via "include", but in e-mail result is 0, there is no generated result from form.

Comment: @Serbon : we need to see the form from which you actually get the posted data

Comment: @Serbon : on you page, you have **2** form `<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">` and `<form id="form1" form action="/kalkukator/index.php" method="post">` and as far as I can understand, you first use a page to calculate some total for the month. Correct ? Then, is that the result that you call `$dnevna` and need to re-use later on ?

Comment: Index.php is a page with variables and formulas, also there is html table where is input fields for days (1-31). File "sendmail.php" is just a script for sending.  Let's say that i need to "print to a mail"  variable called "dnevne", but that variable have value only when values inputed via form are calculated.

Comment: therefore, I suggest you either a/ separate your forms, and make 1 page to calculate + 1 page to set all $vars b/ use jQuery in the 'calculate form', and use response to set the input that will hold the result of calculation. THEN, you process to mail

Comment: Is there any easier way to print results to e-mail?

Comment: well, as long as you need some data / calculation, I don't think you can do it the way you try... It's not that hard stuff to do, just separate things, you'll not write a lot more code, and it will be more readable for future use.

Comment: I separate variables.php, sendmail.php and index.php (in index.php there is form with inputs)...You think like this?

Comment: @Serbon : `index.php` -> name + email + month _then_ `variables.php` -> save *name / email / month* in hidden input, and add choices for each day _then_ -> process to `sendmail.php` where you catch all $vars and -> email : sounds good ? :)

Comment: Everything sounds fine, just this one is not clear for me "save name / email / month in hidden input, and add choices for each day then ", can you give me one row as example?

Comment: well, as you use 3 pages, you need to transfer data form page to page. Therefore, when user validates on page one, you catch the inputs data on page2 and put it in hidden input fields, just under `<form>` -> ie: `<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo"$email"; ?>" />` **IMPORTANT** : on top of that page, you must catch each $_POST value -> $email = $_POST['email']; (according to input name from previous page). And repeat for each input/page

Comment: On index.php , <form method="post" action="sendmail.php"> or "variables.php" insteed sendmail.php?

Comment: I personnally would get first `"name + email + month"` then post all data to `variables.php` where I would calculate for each day 1-31 than finally, to 3rd page and `email`all data

Comment: can you post each page on a separate pastebin please ?

Comment: @Serbon : you're welcome :) great ! some more (good) coding to come ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to use sessions. Put `session_start();` at the top of each page where you want to use a session variable.

Then add your $xyz variable to it as follows: `$_SESSION['xyz'] = $xzy;`
Then that variable is accessible anywhere that you're using sessions.

Comment: Did you test it? Does it work? Are you getting errors?

Comment: There is no errors but still there is no results also